# Will diode burn out gradually

Tags: diodes

Will a diode burn out gradually over time when exposed to high rated current surges frequently.  We use a fr607 diode for freewheeling. Which comes inside a relay box assembly for a inductive load which is completely closed. After some months we get reports of relay box failures. When we open we find the diodes burnt. We want to know whether diode burn out happens instantly or will it keep working and gradually burn out over time

Comment: It tends to happen pretty instantly, though all semiconductors degrade faster when repeatedly exposed to voltage spikes and or high temperatures for long periods of time.

Comment: This is really a repeat of your question asked within the last hour, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/473401/how-to-calculate-free-wheeling-current-value. You have some comments to be addressed on that.